# Spark Streaming + Kafka Integration : Support new topic subscriptions without requiring restart of the streaming context

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using a **spark streaming application(spark 2.1)** to consume data from **kafka(0.10.1)** topics.**I want to subscribe to new topic without restarting the streaming context**. Is there any way to achieve this?

I can see a jira ticket in apache spark project for the same 
(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10320),Even though it is closed in 2.0 version, I couldn't find any documentation or example to do this. If any of you are familiar with this, please provide me documentation link or example for the same, . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Integration between Spark 2.0.x and Kafka 0.10.x support a subscription *pattern*. [From the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#consumerstrategies):

> SubscribePattern allows you to use a regex to specify topics of
>   interest. Note that unlike the 0.8 integration, using Subscribe or
>   SubscribePattern should respond to adding partitions during a running
>   stream.

You can use a regex pattern to register to all the topics you wish.

```
class SubscribePattern[K, V](
    pattern: java.util.regex.Pattern,
    kafkaParams: java.util.Map[String, Object],
    offsets: java.util.Map[TopicPartition, java.util.Long]
) extends ConsumerStrategy[K, V]
```

Comment: I tried this example, This will not serve my purpose.  SubscribePattern will subscribe to all  the available topic based on the regex. But, if I am adding a topic after starting the application, which falls into same regex, it will not be consumed by same stream. May be my approach is wrong.

Comment: @Shemeem It should support adding Topics on the fly. Are you sure your new topic matches the regex?

Comment: Yes I am sure, It is only consuming from those topics which is there while starting the stream.

Comment: val pattern = Pattern.compile("topic.*");
val consumerStrategy=ConsumerStrategies.SubscribePattern[String,String](pattern, kafkaParams);
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  consumerStrategy
)

Comment: Initially I had just two topics topicA and topicB, It was consuming from those topics. Then I added topicX and produced some data, but it never consumed. but next time application started consuming from all these three.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe multiple topics like topic1,topic2 etc

```
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1,topic2")
  .load()
```

For more information, [kafka Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)

Comment: I want to subscribe to topics dynamically, without stopping the application. consuming from multiple topics at the beginning is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Try using subscribePattern. It might solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution more suitable for my purpose.We can share a 'StreamingContext' instance with different dstreams. For better management we can create separate 'dStream' instance for each topic using same streaming context, this 'dStream' instance you can store in a map with its topic name, so that later you can stop or unsubscribe from that particular topic. Please see the code below for clarity.

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/shemeemsp7/01d21588347b94204c71a14005be8afa.js"></script>
```

Comment: did you manage to achieve subscribing and un-subscribe topic without stopping streaming context or driver? if yes could you share sample

Comment: Example page which given just tell how to start multiple dstream which is never a question .. how did you manage to stop or unsubscribe topic and how to resubscribe it without stopping application or contex